# Download File from Website which is created by Javascript in Qt

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

Fantasy Football Season is starting again, so i try to write my own Draft Assistent for my Fantasy Football League. I want to crawl the information from [FantasyPros](https://www.fantasypros.com/). There are tables, which i can download as .csv files. These downloadable files are created with a script.

For example you have the following site: [FantasyPros RBs](https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/qb.php?week=draft).
There you can download the information from the table below to a .csv file. If one looks in the sourcecode, you will get the following information: The "button" is defined as

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="export pull-right"
style="margin:5px;"><i class="fa fa-fp fa-fp-download"></i></a>
```

and there is this script function defined:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.fantasypros.com/js/fp-csv-export-1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".export").click(function(e) {
        if (regfence(e, "Export CSV")) {
            var csv_filename = 'FantasyPros_Fantasy_Football_Projections_RB.csv';
            exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#data'), csv_filename, 'nfl_projections']);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</script>
```

My aim is now to Save this File to my local directory (or only read it in Qt) to use the provided data. I tried the following, but it didn't work, i have no idea, how to get to the file:

```
view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
view->load(QUrl("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/rb.php"));
connect(view,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(finishLoading(bool)));
void MainWindow::finishLoading(bool) {
    view->page()->runJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"fa fa-fp fa-fp-download\")[0].click();",[] (const QVariant &v) { qDebug() << v.toString(); });
}
```

But then nothing happens. What am I doing wrong or is there an other way to get that .csv file?

Thank you for answering and helping!

Comment: I just checked and the page asks you to be logged in to download the file.

Comment: The url you send web request  seems need to log in to the site. If you don't log in the site doesn't send you the file. I've checked in normal browser without log in.

Comment: A okay, i don't considered that, because i have an account there and i am logged in. So even if i am logged in, i cannot download the file. On code basis, should my approach do what i want?